# Mathematica on Surface Pro X (ARM64)?

Tags: installation, hardware

I've been having trouble installing Mathematica on my Surface Pro X, which is an ARM based machine. I was under the impression that Mathematica worked on Arduino devices, which is somehow similar. I've opened a support ticket but never heard back.

Anything I'm missing ? I think I tried 11.3, I used to have access to previous version through my professional account, but I've only access to a download manager that doesn't allow for installation of previous versions.

For clarification, the main desktop app does not launch, but the kernel does (and yes, it does compute 1+1=2, but sadly the lack of graphical interface prevents me from plotting anything, so it's not that useful).

Many thanks

Comment: This seems like it is a problem best left for [support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=technical). You could also try [community](https://community.wolfram.com)?

Comment: You might also check and see if you are running Mathematica proper and not the kernel by accident.

Comment: I know this isn't the best suited place for that question, but who knows, maybe a kind soul had a similar problem !

Comment: right sure, I can understand that—but if it is an actual bug, then it would be much better if you were to contact them directly. What version do you have installed now? You could also try calling :)

Comment: As a clarification to the Arduino question: Mathematica doesn't run on Arduino boards, but you can operate their inputs and outputs from a connected system running Mathematica and you can deploy code generated with Mathematica on them, thus treating them as "smart pheripherals." Arduino boards have kilobytes to megabytes of memory, while a running Mathematica (or "Wolfram Engine") instance requires gigabytes, so it's no surprise that this is the case.

Comment: @kirma But there is a Mathematica version for the Raspberry Pi (wich is also an ARM processor) that features the graphical notebook interface. I tried it on a Raspberry Pi 2; although it was super slow (the Pi 2 had only have a Gigabyte of RAM and chipset lacked many instructions that speed up numerical code) it was fully functional. Admittedly, quite some time has passed since I tried that. I think it was version 10. So this was before the rewrite of the FrontEnd.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I think Mathematica 12.0 is available for Raspberry Pi. ARM on RPi is completely different beast from AVR and ARM Cortex-M CPUs used on Arduino boards, though. Similarity to Surface Pro X is high, but there the software side is completely different...

Answer (score 6):

Mathematica does not currently support Windows on ARM. The system requirements are here:

https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/system-requirements.html

In addition to what is listed on the systems requirements page, Mathematica works on Linux on the Raspberry Pi computer, which uses a 32-bit ARM architecture:

https://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi/

This is a Linux version, not a Windows one.

Comment: While technically true, you can run the 32-bit x86 version on ARM64.  I've used it briefly on my Lenovo Yoga.  But I'm pretty certain 32-bit support on Windows ended after 12.0.

Comment: @ihojnicki Feel free to edit the answer, I marked it as community wiki. I have never used a Windows ARM system. Maybe I was wrong.